# Android Emulator Stops Unexpectedly before it loads my app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

My Android Emulator used to work fine (emulating a 10.1in tablet with API level 15) but now as it launches I repeatedly get messages that the phone has stopped unexpectedly, the UI has stopped unexpectedly, the calendar has stopped unexpectedly, etc, etc, and I cannot load my app. I have reduced SD capacity to 10M and RAM to 512 but cannot get the emulator to load anything more demanding than a 4 inch phone running API level 10. This is not my app stopping, but the emulator. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Should/can I reload the ARM System Image in Eclipse for instance? If I select the image in the SDK Manager it warns me that if I remove the package it cannot be undone.

Comment: Have you tried to wipe your history from the emulator(clean start)? Or to make a new emulator and try to run your app on that emulator?

Comment: That worked, thank you. I made a new emulator to the same spec and that launches and loads my app. I still get an occasional message that the UI has stopped working but the app continues to run.

Comment: Even better solution is to use the Intel Atom Emulator with HAXM accelerator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow for details. This emulator is much much faster to load.